# psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed on 2nd request:

Tags: python, postgresql

I am using postgres and this is my code to first get id , If it exist then it will delete data against that record with some conditions . So now Issue is 1st time query work fines even record is there but if I run 2nd time this error I get "psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already"

My python code to do this is this :

```
def clean_tables(account_id, node_id, scope_id, node_type):
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        print(account_id, "account_id__")
        check_id_query = "SELECT uuid FROM my_accounts WHERE name = %s"
        cur.execute(check_id_query, (account_id,))
        result = cur.fetchone()

        if result:
            uuid = result[0]
            print("ID:", uuid)
            scope_id_string = "and cmetadata->>'scope_id' = %s" if scope_id else ''
            clean_record_query = "DELETE FROM my_collections WHERE collection_id = %s " \
                                 "AND cmetadata->>'node_type' = %s AND cmetadata->>'node_id' = %s  {}".format(scope_id_string)
            print(clean_record_query , "clean_record_query_")
            cur.execute(clean_record_query, (uuid, node_type, node_id, scope_id))
            conn.commit()

            if cur.rowcount > 0:
                print("Record deleted successfully.")
            else:
                print("No record found to delete.")
        else:
        print("No ID found for the given account_id.")
```

Comment: 1) The error is *...connection already...*. not closed. 2)From docs [connection](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html): *Connections can be used as context managers. ... Note that the connection is not closed by the context and it can be used for several contexts.*. You need to explicitly close the connection. FYI, this changes in `psycopg(3)` per [psycopg2 --> psycopg3](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html):  *In Psycopg 3, using with connection will close the connection at the end of the with block, making handling the connection resources more familiar.*